# Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : Login failed for user 'SA'

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, docker, asp.net-core

I am running a SQL Server database on docker using `microsoft/mssql-server-linux:2017-latest` image.

The database connection string in `appsettings.json` is defined as:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=sql.data,1433;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;User Id=SA;Password=Pass@word"
  },
```

and the database service is defined as the following in the `docker-compose.yml`:

```
  sql.data:
    image: microsoft/mssql-server-linux:2017-latest
    environment:
      - ID=SA
      - PASSWORD=Pass@word
      - ACCEPT_EULA=Y
    ports:
      - "1433:1433"
```

When I try to connect to the database (using Entity Framework) in my application, I get the following error:

> SqlException: Login failed for user 'SA'.

To debug it, I login to the docker image, and try to access the database from the docker using the following command:

```
/opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U SA -P "Pass@word"
```

then I get the following error:

> Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : Login failed for user 'SA'..

I have tried `"` (double-quotation), `'` (single-quotation), and without quoting the username and password, and any combination  of both, but still get the same error.

Comment: Did you set this server up? Is the sa account disabled perhaps? Can you connect via SSMS?

Comment: No, I do not set the server, it is the official docker image with no changes. Not very familiar with MS SQL, how do I SSMS?!

Comment: SSMS is MSFT's tool for connecting to, maintaining and querying MS SQL Server, so using a different tool besides ODBC will tell you if it's the login/password or ODBC. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Linux, hey? Have you tried lowercase `sa` instead of uppercase `SA`?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning, yes I did, but did not work.

Comment: @FembotDBA not sure how I can connect a sql server running on docker to SSMS; it does not seem to be seeing the db!?

Comment: Sorry, really hard to know for sure, but it it wasn't running at all the error message would not be "Login failed for user 'SA'" like you state above. I tried to read through MSFT's help page on connecting (below), you sure the password is what you've provided? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/quickstart-install-connect-docker?view=sql-server-2017&pivots=cs1-bash

Comment: I have double-checked the password, and don't see any mismatch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `Password` with `SA_Password` in connection string:

```
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=sql.data,1433;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;User Id=SA;SA_Password=Pass@word"
  },
```

Answer (score 5):

Try adding '(quotation mark) around your username and password :
 'sa'
 'Pass@word'

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
"DefaultConnection": "Server=sql.data,1433;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;User Id='SA';Password='Pass@word'"
```

},